# QGis draw over simple jpeg image

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I'm pretty new to GIS, and since 2 months ago QGIS is a great tool to achieve very simple tasks, such open some shapefiles I find in the web and load that data on my website geoJSON formatted.

Now I'm looking forward to produce my own data, since I need the shapes of boroughs and neighbourhoods of my city and it is not available anywhere..

I've tried some things, and In my first very original idea (dream) it looked very simple... Like: open my actual city bounds layer, put and image layer behind it, resize the image to fit it, and click on that yellow pencil to fast have a beautiful hand made map... Now, after lot of hours I realize that it is not that simple...

Anyway, after some reading I could place my image on the map... I have a neigh_image_layer on which I see my full scaled beautiful JPG.

The 1st problem I faced was that my city_bounds shapefile layer was not showing anymore in the map canvas after adding the image, so.. fixing some CRS matters on image load I could place both visible, but now since my city polygon is in the right place in the middle of Brasil, my image is probably placed over an area that would wrap the whole planet.

There is any simple way to redimension the image behind the map layer? And better, am I trying the correct approach? I read tons of stuff, but maybe I don't know the correct name of the procedures I'm doing.

[image]

Comment: I am worried that you are trying to resize your city-bounds shapefile to fit the image.  Please can you confirm how you are adding the image (e.g. in Map Composer or in the main QGIS window) and is the image georeferenced (if you are not sure, then tell us where/how you got it or post a link to it).

Comment: Hey, thanks! I'm sure my image is nor georeferenced, I just got it from google images. I just dragged it to the map canvas, and it was put as a GDAL layer. Here is a screenshot of what I have: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ujlkaayd4otfcv1/Screenshot%202014-02-20%2012.59.57.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to georeference your image. Look for Georeferencer tool in Raster menu.

[Here](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/02/tutorial-georeferencing-topo-sheets.html) you have a good guide in "how to georeference a image in qgis".

It is for QGIS 1.7.2, but there aren't major changes in current version.

Comment: That's exactly what I was not able to google!! Thank you very much